# Application Debug Level Log Messages on WebSphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I just start working on maintaining a Spring application which is deployed on WebSphere enterprise (version 8.5). It is my first time using the container. I need to have log messages in the debug level for tracing down a bug. The bug error log message shows up in the trace.log. After the system admin configures the container log level to debug, we don't see any debug level log messages. The application didn't have a log property file although log4j and Slf4j are its dependencies. I add a log4j.properties file which configures both a log file output and the console output. I, however, don't see the log file nor any log messages on console according to the system admin. It seems to me that the debug log level configuration is special in Websphere. How to solve this log level configuration problem?

The followings are Java code segment

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class MyClass {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

  public void method01(){

    log.debug("....");
}
```

and the property file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/portal-server.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C:%M:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C:%M:%L - %m%n
```

Notes: ${SERVER_LOG_ROOT} is replaced by a real path on the container box without a luck either.

Comment: Open some code which should log and check import statements. If you can see: org.slf4j.Logger your application is using slf4j, org.apache.log4j.Logger means log4j logging and java.util.logging.Logger is java.util logging. WebSphere can intervene only in case of java.util logger. Please update you question with information about specific logging which you need.

Comment: I add some code segment for an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is using log4j logger trough the slf4j logging interface. This is a pretty standard setup. WebSphere doesn't interfere with this kind of logging configuration.

These are steps for proper setup of this configuration:

1. First exclude commons-logging dependency from your project. It is a popular logging interface required by Spring and various different projects. Instead, we will use slf4j.
2. Add dependencies to:

   - slf4j-api       - our logging interface
   - jcl-over-slf4j  - commons-logging implementation
   - slf4j-log4j12 - sl4j log4j bridge
   - log4j         - logging api
3. Create log4j.properties in /WEB-INF/log4j.properties location.
4. Bootstrap log4j. Simplest way to bootstrap in spring web app is by using Log4jConfigListener utility class. Add following entries to web.xml. You should add this at the very top of web.xml in order to bootstrap logging before anything other happens.

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

That's it. This should work.

Now that logging is working you should probably make more detailed configuration with console logging during development; and more concise logging in deployment.The simplest way to do it is by using parameterized configuration log4j.properties:

```properties
log4j.rootLogger=${LOG4J_SERVER_LOGLEVEL}, fileAppender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
... console appender configuration ...
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
... file appender configuration ..
```

In a production LOG4J_SERVER_LOGLEVEL environment variable is set to "INFO". On my development machine, it is set to "DEBUG, console". This way servers log only to fileAppender, and development machine logs to console and fileAppender.

You can always add more environment variables to fine tune specific loggers or even make log4j.properties external and provide "file:" location as *param-value*. In case of external log4j.properties Log4jConfigListener can be setup to monitor changes in log4j properties and change the logging configuration in real time.

Nothing of this is WebSphere specific and these steps are the same in any Java web container. Now if you **need** logging which is configurable from WebSphere console you can accomplish this by replacing log4j with jul logger. WebSphere provides admin interface for jul logging under "Logs and trace" section.

Comment: Thank very much for your input. I will try it and see how that goes. I don't have a direct access to the WS. So, I have to rely on others to give me the log result.